# I tried to save an array in MatLab and it destroyed my file

Tags: arrays, matlab, delete-file

Total coding/matlab noob here.

I was having trouble saving a 1x200 cell array of names, called 'names'. Every time I closed the file after saving, upon reopening the array would be gone. Looking at the matlab website I found that you could save variables to the file using the function save('pqfile.mat','p','q'), where p and q are the variables. So I did save('myfilename.mat','names') and it destroyed my existing code. Now the file looks like this:

```
MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Tue Nov 29 11:23:54 2016     
¢"¢#b"b#â"â#"#  ’"’#R"R#
Ò"Ò#2"2#²"²#r"r#ò"ò£
¢
£Š¢Š£J¢J£Ê¢Ê£*¢*£     
ª¢ª£j¢j£ê¢ê£¢£  š¢š£Z¢Z£
Ú¢Ú£:¢:#]ÐÝÐ=Ð½Ð}ÐýÐ0ƒ0C0Ã0#0£0c0ã00“0S0Ó030³0s0ó0°‹°K°Ë°+°«°k°ë°°›°[°Û°;°»°{°û°p‡pGpÇp'p§pgpçpp—pWp×p7p·pwp÷pð?ðOðÏð/ð~Æ/x‰Wx?7x‹wx?øˆOøŒ/øŠoøŽø¿áwüt~R4ƒ1€Á‚!Š¡†aŽá?‰‘…Q?Ñƒ1‹±‡q?ñ™€  ™ˆ‰™„I™ŒÉ™‚)™Š©™†i™Žé™?™‰™™…Y™?Ù™ƒ9™‹¹™‡y™?ùY€Yˆ…Y„EYŒÅY‚%YŠ¥Y†eYŽåY?Y‰•Y…UY?ÕYƒ5Y‹µY‡uY?õÙ€
Ùˆ?Ù„MÙŒÍÙ‚-ÙŠ­Ù†mÙŽíÙ?Ù‰?È.ìÊnìÎìÉ^ìÍ>ìË~ìÏÈAÌ!ÊaÎÉQÍ1ËqÏ  œÈIœÌ)œÊiœÎœÉYœÍ9œËyœÏ\ÈE\Ì%\Êe\Î\ÉU\Í5\Ëu\Ï
```

etc.

I believe the problem was i saved it as the file name of my existing code, thinking that it would just save the variable to the code so i could have it in there when i reopen the file. is there any way to recover my old file?

If that file is erased forever, I'd love an answer to my earlier question (lol). I'm sure it has an easy solution, I'm just very inexperienced.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MAT files are binary, not plaintext. You're not going to be able to read them in a text editor. Use [`load`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html). It should not have overwritten your code, MATLAB code is saved as `*.m`, not `*.mat`. If you *were* saving your code as a `*.mat` file then you're SOL.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but when I use load I only get the error `Undefined variable "myfilename" or class "myfilename.m"`

Comment: How do you expect anyone to be able to answer what's wrong when you aren't providing what you're trying to use? We're not omniscient.

Comment: Like I said, I used `load(myfilename.m)` and got that error message. That's all I know. At this point, I will just recreate the original code -- thank you for trying to help. However, I still need to figure out how to save my array of names; perhaps I will create another question.

Comment: No, that's not what you said. You said "when I use load" and not *how* you used load, which is an important detail. If you [**read the documentation** you would see that the filename needs to be a string](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html#inputarg_filename). `myfilename.m` is not a string, `'myfilename.m'` is a string. According to your question it's also not the name of your file. `'myfilename.mat'` is the name of your file.

Comment: sorry about that. after doing it again, I get the message `Number of columns on line 2 of ASCII file myfilename.m must be
the same as previous lines.` and when I try to use `text = fileread( 'myfilename.m' )`, the result is the gibberish I put above. Does this mean my file really has been converted to that gibberish? Thanks!